# How to disable SQLAlchemy´s lazy loading?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I´m developing a python app which uses Flask-SQLAlchemy and it´s ORM Mapper.
I´ve got two tables with a Many To One relation. The main problem is that I want to load the content of both Objects with one join query and not later, when I access the object of the child table.
I already tried to get these behavior by using the joinedload option like this:

```py
Event.query.filter(Event.timestamp == day)
.join(Event.user)
.options(joinedload(Event.user))
.all()
```

Also tried to set the `lazy="joined"` attribute in the entity-class for the relationship, which caused no difference.

The SQL Query looks right and the join is correctly generated, but if I access the user attribute later, another join query is sent. With other strategies it´s also not working, like the `contains_eager` option.
So the expected behavior would be, to save all information on the first load and don´t execute a query later on.

All SQLAlchemy options are default, except the DATABASE_URI. Is there any global option to disable this behavior or to override the default?

The Entities are the following:

```py
class Event(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "event"
    __table_args__ = (
        db.ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ["username", "userfirstname"], ["users.name", "users.firstname"]
        ),
    )
    timestamp = db.Column(db.Date, primary_key=True, index=True)
    username= db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    userfirstname= db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    ...

    user = db.relationship("UserEntity")

class UserEntity(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    name= db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    firstname= db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

Comment: Since you don't have a ForeignKey-column I'm not sure if SQLAlchemy is able to resolve the join condition for you automagically - have you tried explicitly defining the `username` column as ForeignKey relation to the `name` field in UserEntity in the _type_ definition? (and not as tableargs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve found the mistake. The basic idea of disabling lazyloading was right and worked fine. I just messed up the object refs on the validation step and destroyed the SQLAlchemy background logic.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class Event(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "event"
    __table_args__ = (
        db.ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ["username", "userfirstname"], ["users.name", "users.firstname"]
        ),
    )
    timestamp = db.Column(db.Date, primary_key=True, index=True)
    username= db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    userfirstname= db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    user = db.relationship("UserEntity", back_populates="events")
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    

class UserEntity(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    name= db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    firstname= db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    events = relationship(MyOtherClass, lazy='joined')
```

from sqlalchemy docs:

```
joined applies a JOIN to the given SELECT statement so that related rows are loaded in the same result set. Joined eager loading is detailed at Joined Eager Loading.
```

Comment: I tried it (just without user_id, because I dont have one, because its a composite key), but it still executes single sql statements, when i access the user attribute of an event. I loaded the event with `Event.query.filter(Event.timestamp == day).join(Event.user).all()`